# Sharing FAT32 partition on external SSD setup with windows

Tags: partitioning, windows, files, sharing

I am having a problem managing storage space. I am running Ubuntu 14.04LTS on an external SSD so I can access my work from multiple computers.  I partitioned the total 65gb SSD into 3 sections.  55GB for Ubuntu (ext3 file system).  5GB swap space.  And the last section I made roughly 3GB of FAT32 space in the attempt to be able to back up my spreadsheets and address lists on this space and have access to the them via a windows computer as if it was just a 3GB thumb stick however when I plug it into windows it tells me the drive is broken and needs to be formatted.

My question is, can this be done so that windows will recognize the 3GB FAT32 partition as just a hard drive and ignore the Linux partitions?

Comment: I think that you can try to put the FAT partition at the beginning, formatting via Windows itself. Then you go back to Gparted and without touching that FAT partition you put two other partitions. Note that you *should* align the partition at the cilinders to get the highest compatiblity.

Comment: Windows requires external drives to have one partition.

Comment: @enedil that's false. I have an external drive with one NTFS partition and one ext4 partition and Windows sees the NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Ubuntu and partitioned the drive as follows:
1st fat32 5 GB
2nd EXT4 (Ubuntu) 52GB
3rd swap area 5GB

Windows recognizes the 5 GB drive and that is all which is what I needed.  So from what I gather windows can not look past the first partition if it is not in a "windows friendly" format.

Comment: "Windows would not see partition formatted to NTFS using Gparted" I think this is not true.